# JavaEE 6 Servlet for long polling

Tags: java, ajax, glassfish, comet

I've tried to create async-servlet for long-polling, using [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/async-servlet/async-servlets.html) on my Glassfish server, however it didn't work well, the POST requests were too long (timed out) and GET returned sometimes void response with "Error parsing XML file" firebug message. Can somebody please provide simple async-servlet for handling long-polling requests?

Comment: what kind of long polling are you doing? Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: I'm trying to write simple chat application, so the javascript creates long-polling request and waits until the server sends message.

Answer (score 0):

It is better you move away from the servlet based approach if you want to implement a long polling solution. [Netty](http://netty.io/) is very good choice for such applications. Just build a simple HTTP instance with child.keepAlive option in bootstrap kept to true (server doesnt close off the client connections). That way you don't need to deal with the servlet containers time out and connection handling intricacies. Netty is an asynchronous IO framework and should give you great performance matrix.